# How to implement push notification in Android

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm, pooling, mqtt

i am developing app that would receive data from server any time. i have searched some mechanism to do this
**C2DM:** but i require Google account for each device on which app will be installed

**MQTT:** but it is a Third party and a person for which i am developing does not trust third party because he says in future may be that third party start charging for their service or even stop their service.

**Pooling:** which is again not a good idea because it consume lot of battery

**Is there any better way of doing this..**
i have posted similar question before but did not get a satisfactory answer and i am still confused...

Comment: MQTT is a protocol. It has precisely as many "parties" as you want it to have.

Comment: @CommonsWare i didn't got your point ? can u elaborate

Comment: You wrote, regarding MQTT, "it is a Third party". It is not. It is a protocol. It is not a "party". You wrote, regarding MQTT, "does not trust third party because he says in future may be that third party start charging for their service or even stop their service". MQTT is a protocol. It is not a party. Some MQTT server hosting service would be a party, and it could possibly have fees involved. You are welcome to host your own MQTT server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward and reliable way to implement this is by using **C2DM**.  Requiring a Google account on each device shouldn't be a big deal, because users need that anyway to access the Android Market.  The only major exception to worry about will be Kindle Fire users.

This blog post has a good listing of alternative ways to roll your own push service: http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/.  However, you need to think if the extra effort (including maintenance) is going to be worthwhile.

Comment: actually i am developing this for a company which has thousands of member so my client won't let me use this because he says we can't let this to each member to create separate Google account for himself.

Comment: Just about every Android phone already has a Google account associated with it, since it is required for using the Android market.  Unless you know this does not apply to your userbase, it would make sense to leverage their existing Google accounts.